# Proving Wald's second equation using Optional Stopping Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, random-walk

I am working on an exercising about proving Wald's second equation, which is as follows:

> Let $S_n = \xi_1 + \cdots + \xi _n$ where $\xi _i$ are independent, $\mathbb{E} \xi_1 = 0$
> and $\text{Var}(\xi_1) = \sigma^2 < \infty$. Show that if $T$ is a stopping time with $\mathbb{E} T < \infty$ then $\mathbb{E} S ^2 _T = \sigma^2 \mathbb{E} T$.

I am aware and understand proof of the above statement using an $L^2$ convergence theorem, see [this](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Epsdey/MATH561SP21/week12.pdf). However, I have tried proving this with the Optional Stopping theorem but to no avail. The exact statement of the theorem is as follows:

> *Optional Stopping Theorem*
> Suppose $X_n$ is a martingale and $\mathbb{E}(|X_{n+1} - X_n| | \mathcal{F}_n) \leq B$ a.s.
> for some $B < \infty$. If $N$ is a stopping time with $\mathbb{E} N < \infty$  then $X _{N \wedge n}$ is uniformly integrable and hence $\mathbb{E} X_N = \mathbb{E} X_0$.

Suppose $\mathbb{F}_n = \sigma(\xi_1 , \dots, \xi _n)$. To use this theorem, $\mathbb{E}T < \infty$ had been given. Let
$$
  X_n = S ^2 _n - n \sigma^2,
$$
which is a martingale, we need to show $\mathbb{E}(|X_{n+1} - X_n| | \mathcal{F}_n) \leq B$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}(|X_{n+1} - X_n| | \mathcal{F}_n)
    &= \mathbb{E}(|S^2 _{n+1} - S^2 _n - \sigma^2 | | \mathcal{F}_n) \\
    &\leq \mathbb{E}(|S^2 _{n+1} - S^2 _n| | \mathcal{F}_n) + \sigma^2 \\ 
    &\leq \mathbb{E}(|(S _{n+1} - S _n) (S _{n+1} + S _n)| | \mathcal{F}_n) + \sigma^2 \\
    &\leq \mathbb{E}(|\xi _{n+1} (\xi _{n+1} + 2 S _n)| | \mathcal{F}_n) + \sigma^2 \\
    &\leq \mathbb{E} (\xi _{n+1} ^2 | \mathcal{F}_n )
    + 2 \mathbb{E} (|\xi _{n+1} S _n| | \mathcal{F}_n )
    + \sigma^2  \\
    &\leq \mathbb{E} (\xi _{n+1} ^2 )
    + 2 |S _n| \cdot \mathbb{E} (|\xi _{n+1}| )
    + \sigma^2 \tag{*} \\ 
    &\leq \sigma^2
    + 2 |\sigma| |S _n|
    + \sigma^2
\end{align*}
$$
where (*) follows from $\xi _{n + 1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$ and $S_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable. This is where I get stuck as I cannot bound $|S_n|$ by a finite number.

I tried replacing $n$ by $n \wedge T$, but it would not help as neither $\xi_i$'s nor $T$ are bounded. I also thought about using another stopping time, say
$$
    N_a = \inf \{n : S_n \not \in (-a , a) \}. \tag{1}
$$
I think it can be shown that $\mathbb{E}N_a < \infty$. Then
$$
    \mathbb{E}(|X_{(n+1) \wedge T \wedge N_a} - X_{n \wedge T \wedge N_a}| | \mathcal{F}_n)
    \leq 2\sigma^2 + 2|\sigma|a,
    \tag{2}
$$
and we can use the Optional Stopping Theorem on it to get
$$
    0 = \mathbb{E} X_0 = \mathbb{E} X_{T \wedge N_a}.
$$
But to make the right-hand side $X_T$ one need to take $a \to \infty$. I am not sure if this violates the stopping time (1) or the bound (2).

Please contribute if you have any thought or idea on this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do the $L^2$ massaging with this too, right? Argue that $N_a \to \infty$ a.s. as $a \to \infty$. Then you have $$ \mathbb{E}[S_{T\wedge N_a}^2] = \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}[T\wedge N_a] \le \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}[T],$$ and of course $T \wedge N_a \to T,$ $S_{T\wedge N_a} \to S_T$ a.s., and you're done (DCT for RHS, a.s. + uniformly bounded second moment for the LHS).

Comment: Same thing works with studying $S_{T \wedge n}$ btw: the optional sampling theorem for bounded stopping times (like $T \wedge n \le n$) doesn't require bounded increments. This is arguably simpler since you don't need to worry about the behaviour of $N_a$.

Comment: I understand this, and it is the way that I do this problem. I am just wondering if the Optional Stopping theorem can be used. The thing is that the textbook spent a long passage on the Optional Stopping theorems, yet in practice DCT, MCT and BCT can almost do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, but, you _have_ used the optional stopping theorem, right, to claim that $\mathbb{E}[S^2_{T \wedge N_a}] = \sigma^2 \mathbb{E}[T \wedge N_a]$? I guess the other observation is that if the conditional variances are all $\sigma^2$ then the same observation follows, and at least I don't find this very obvious with just the standard measure theory technology.

Comment: I guess if you're asking why optional stopping is an interesting result, this is a bit of a fundamental theorem, really: think of martingales as wealth processes of a gambler, and stopping times as exit strategies. Then optional stopping is really saying that (for reasonable stopping times/processes), you can't fudge about with the history and pull out wins out of nowhere if the game is fair. This is pretty fundamental, and will show up just about everywhere (e.g. the fundamental theorems of asset pricing, game-theoretic statitics etc). Simpler proofs of Wald's identities is just a plus :)

Comment: That is true, but only because I am considering the additional stopping time $N_a$. If we are using DCT then there is no need to use $N_a$. We can just apply it to $\mathbb{E} X _{n \wedge T}$.

Comment: Another potential problem when using DCT to $N_a$ is that I cannot gaurantee $T \leq N_a$ unless I take $a \to \infty$. But then the bound for the martingale difference will not be finite.